# mysqldump―which charackters are escaped

Tags: mysql

Which characters does mysqldump escape when generating the dump file? Unfortunately couldn't I find any documentation for this, so I played around and found out that **only double quotes, single quotes and backslashes** (',",\) are escaped by a backslash.

But are there any more, or is there any documentation for anywhere available?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for character escapes is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html).

From the table in that link, the following are escaped...

> \0    An ASCII NUL (0x00) character.
>
> \' A single quote (“'”) character.
>
> \"    A double quote (“"”) character.
>
> \b    A backspace character.
>
> \n    A newline (linefeed) character.
>
> \r    A carriage return character.
>
> \t    A tab character.
>
> \Z    ASCII 26 (Control+Z).
>
> \    A backslash (“\”) character.
>
> \%    A “%” character.
>
> \_   A “_” character.

Comment: Please excuse my late response, but thanks for that that link!